# How to get top 5 based on column 1

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

```
RDD = [('B000002KXA', 'Music', 'Rescue Me', 1), ('6302049040', 'Movies & TV', 'Pennies from Heaven [VHS]', 2), ('B000002OKC', 'Music', 'Country Music Hall of Fame', 1), ('6304174616', 'Movies & TV', 'Star Blazers Series 1: The Quest for Iscandar (6pc) (Coll) [VHS]', 1), ('630265288X', 'Movies & TV', 'The Kathy Kaehler Fitness System [VHS]', 1), ('B000002H3Z', 'Music', 'London 0 Hull 4', 3), ('6304071841', 'Movies & TV', 'Romeo &amp; Juliet [VHS]', 2), ('0790732475', 'Movies & TV', 'Batman &amp; Robin [VHS]', 1), ('0471178411', 'Books', 'Microsoft Exchange 5 Sourcebook', 2), ('6300271765', 'Movies & TV', 'Sphinx [VHS]', 1)]
```

RDD structure is (id, category, title, count).

I need to get a total of 5 counts based on each category.

I tried to use .takeOrdered() function. Did not achieve the result.

I know that convert to DataFrame and do a rank easily. However, the requirement is only using RDD.

Answer (score 0):

The takeOrdered(n, key) function in RDD allows sorting by values from particular column and returning n number of rows after sorting.

```
RDD.takeOrdered(5,lambda x: x[3])
```

- Reference : [takeOrdered](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.takeOrdered.html?highlight=takeordered#pyspark.RDD.takeOrdered)

Answer (score 0):

You can sort in reverse order and get the first five elements.

```
sorted(RDD, key=lambda item: item[3], reverse=True)[:5]
```

will give you...

```
[('B000002H3Z', 'Music', 'London 0 Hull 4', 3),
 ('6302049040', 'Movies & TV', 'Pennies from Heaven [VHS]', 2),
 ('6304071841', 'Movies & TV', 'Romeo &amp; Juliet [VHS]', 2),
 ('0471178411', 'Books', 'Microsoft Exchange 5 Sourcebook', 2),
 ('B000002KXA', 'Music', 'Rescue Me', 1)]
```

Comment: This function sorted() throw error. No such function exists.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. The [Sorted(..)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function was introduced as early as v2.4 (with key), I think. Are you using an older version of python? There are no additional imports required either